# Changing refresh rate in gnome to anything but zero

Tags: linux, gnome, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have an older Red Hat Enterprise box (2012) here running Gnome 2.28.2 with Metacity 2.28.0. I connected a Samsung 1920 x 1080 screen with a VGA cable but when it's connected, the refresh rate is 0Hz which I am guessing is the cause of the mouse cursor flickering and sometimes disappearing. I have come to this conclusion because the Red Hat box running next to it is the same version and same version of Gnome, but connected to a Dell monitor via VGA, xrandr shows the output is set to 59.9 Hz (60.0) and the mouse cursor flickering/disappearing issue does not happen.

I have tried a multitude of ways of adding 59.9/60.0Hz options but nothing seems to work or I seem to get various warnings/errors.

xrandr shows this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
 default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
    1920x1080       0.0* 
    1280x1024       0.0  
    1024x768        0.0  
    800x600         0.0  
    640x480         0.0  
    1920x1080_60.00   60.0  
   1920x1080_59.90 (0x1a5)  173.0MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock   67.2KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock   60.0Hz
```

I have tried several ways of adding a new resolution, as you can see the last 2 versions of 1920x1080 I was able to add. The one with 59.90 is actually wrong and I am trying to delete it with:

> xrandr --delmode default "1920x1080_59.90"

Unfortunately it always gives me "Failed to get size of gamma for output default" followed by:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  150 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (RRDeleteOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  20
```

The correct mode with 60Hz has the correct values so I tried activating it:

> xrandr --output default --mode "1920x1080_60.00"

- the screen flickers for 1 second (as if changing output modes)
- xrandr output says it's still running the original 1920 x 1080 with 0.0 Hz
- Warning "Failed to get size of gamma for output default"

xorg.conf:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Videocard0"
    Driver "vesa"
EndSection
```

lsmod | grep i915:

```
i915                  624511  0 
drm_kms_helper         44321  1 i915
drm                   280012  2 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit            5935  1 i915
i2c_core               31084  5 i2c_i801,i915,drm_kms_helper,drm,i2c_algo_bit
video                  20674  1 i915
```

lspci -k:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1998
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: What is your display card and which DDX driver (xf86-video-*) are you using? Can you attach a copy of your Xorg log?

Comment: Added video card info to my question; How do I determine which DDX driver I'm using? I can't include xorg.log because it's 16MB (and also probably for security reasons)... which part would you like to see?

Comment: 16MB? That itself sounds weird enough. I guess `grep -i module` on the log will do but I don't know if it makes sense on your abnormally huge one...

Comment: Would be good if you can confirm the kernel module `i915` is loaded (`lsmod | grep i915` or `lspci -k` and look for `Kernel driver in use: i915` under the VGA controller). Also what about attaching your xorg CONF?

Comment: Updated the question with relevant details you requested. I also found no references to i915 in xorg.conf or should I look for something else?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the xorg conf and restart X should be your solution.

Xorg should load the appropriate DDX driver (`intel_drv.so` included in the `xorg-x11-drv-intel` package, or older equivalence) automatically, especially when the kernel driver (`i915`) is in use.

So make sure the `xorg-x11-drv-intel` package is installed as well.

In case it still doesn't work, you can also try (re)starting X with the xorg conf but with `vesa` replaced with `intel`:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Videocard0"
    Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

The "vesa" DDX driver only provides primitive features and should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: After deleting the file, the system boots normally but `xrandr` still shows the same output. I tried replacing `vesa` with `intel` but the system wouldn't boot so I reverted back to the original xorg.conf, however I can't connect via VNC anymore, in fact my VNC client just hangs. I am now attempting to install the `xorg-x11-drv-intel` package.

Comment: Ok I think I managed to install the latest version (found via rpmfind.net). After rebooting, xorg.conf has mysteriously disappeared, VNC clients are still crashing and I'm still using a 0Hz configuration.

Comment: I doubt that `the latest version (found via rpmfind.net)` will work for you anyway. I assumed that the official repo (or whichever repo you got your `xorg-x11-server` package from) has the `xorg-x11-drv-intel` package for you as well. If it's not the case you'll probably need to build from source of a version that will work with your xorg server.

Comment: I inherited this server and I unfortunately have no idea which repo was originally used. I grabbed the latest from rpmfind (and installed via yum) because I couldn't find any other newer versions to download. I shall continue down this path though.

Comment: Thing is you may need an older version instead of the current or a newer one...can't you check the repos that have been added for `yum`?

Comment: I'm still learning how to use Linux so it takes a me a lot longer to decipher what you're asking - plus I don't always have access to the machine. I'll get back to you on this. I awarded you the bounty because you're the only one helping me get through this mess :)